# Laravel - Form select categories from database

Tags: php, laravel, select

I have database tables 'Events' and 'Categories'. 
I want to assign a category to an event using a select dropdown in the form. I also want to be able to edit it and update it. The code I have currently given me the following error -

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'category_id' cannot be null

**addEvent.blade.php**

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::Label('category_id', 'Category:') !!}
        <select> class="form-control" name="category_id">
          @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option value='{{ $category->id}}'> {{ $category->category}}</option>
          @endforeach
         </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**eventController**

```
public function addEvent(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request, [
    'event_name'  => 'required',
    'start_date'  => 'required',
    'end_date'    => 'required',
    'time'        => 'required',
    'trip_id'     => 'required',

  ]);

    $start_date = Carbon::parse($request['start_date'])->format('Y-m-d');
    $end_date = Carbon::parse($request['end_date'])->format('Y-m-d');

    $tripCheck = Trip::where('id', $request['trip_id'])
    ->whereDate('startdate', '<=', $start_date)
    ->whereDate('enddate', '>=', $start_date)

    ->whereDate('startdate', '<=', $end_date)
    ->whereDate('enddate', '>=', $end_date)
    ->first();

    if ($tripCheck) {

      $events = new Events;
      $trips = Trip::all();
      $categories = Categories::pluck('category','id');
      $events->category_id = $request['category_id'];
      $events->colour =  $request['colour'];
      $events->event_name = $request['event_name'];
      $events->start_date = $request['start_date'];
      $events->end_date = $request['end_date'];
      $events->time = $request['time'];
      $events->address = $request['address'];
      $events->notes = $request['notes'];
      $events->trip_id = $request['trip_id'];
      $events->save();

return redirect('trips')->with('success', 'The new event has been added to your trip')->with('trips', $trips)->withCategories($categories);
} else
  {
  return redirect('trips')->withErrors(['The dates you added are not within Trip start and end date.']);
   }


public function display($id)
{
  $categories = Categories::all();

  return view('/addEvent')->with('trip_id', $id)->withCategories($categories);
}
```

**editEvent**

```
<div class="form-group"> Category:
      <input type="select" name="category" class="form-control" value="{{$events->category}}" placeholder="Category" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Off question : Why you use `$trips = Trip::all();` on your controller?

Comment: Change your all code like this, from `$events->category_id = $request['category_id']` to  `$events->category_id = $request->category_id;`

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'category_id' cannot be null

Comment: Would you please dd the request by,  `dd($request->all());`

Comment: array:9 [▼
  "_token" => "C8tVGYt6b7ugGLb0JaQ2TBhq5Wc1QZSgziymA4FR"
  "trip_id" => "17"
  "colour" => "#000000"
  "event_name" => "test"
  "start_date" => "2020-03-03"
  "end_date" => "2020-03-03"
  "time" => "12:30"
  "address" => "test"
  "notes" => null
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing your `<select>` too early. Change

`<select> class="form-control" name="category_id">`

to

`<select class="form-control" name="category_id">`

to make it have a `name`, `class` etc